# How to make webpage display as a square?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Not sure if I have to use an iframe,CSS or how,but  what I want to do is to have a webpage display as square.To have height to be %100 but for the width to be the same size of the height, making it a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vh` (viewport height). Add `margin: auto;` if you want to center it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.square {
  background: pink;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<iframe id="square" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d6225.402678457221!2d35.47883967506326!3d38.72466541839045!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x152b121b553844bb%3A0x127fda1b7d9790b2!2sGevhernesibe%2C+38010+Kocasinan%2FKayseri!5e0!3m2!1str!2str!4v1484265875494" width="600" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

js

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

$("#square").attr("width",$("#square").height());

});
```

anywhere in html document.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#square").attr("width",$("#square").height());

});
</script>
```

Comment: @faith Topcu,  how or were do you add the JS, I am new to JS.

Comment: anywhere in html document. 

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#square").attr("width",$("#square").height());

});
</script>

Comment: Not sure why I am seeing a map and one that is tiny. And is there a way to do it without an iframe, so just the page loads as a square?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS only solution:

Wrap the iframe in a div container. Make this div container square using the `pseudo-element` padding trick. Position the iframe absolutely inside this container. Best of all this solution is **responsive** and requires **no js**.

```
.iframe-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.iframe-container::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.iframe-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxZPyy

Comment: Can I do it without an iframe, just to have the current page load in that ratio?